# Converting From ScheduleAtFixedRate To CachedThreadPool

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

The thread below runs every 12-24 hours, and I don't want to have an idle thread in the pool. The current code is:

```
private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
...
scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> getLastestJson(), INITIAL_DELAY, CHECK_INTERVAL, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

How can I leverage `newCachedThreadPool()` in this case where CHECK_INTERVAL > 12hrs. The duration of the operation is < 15 sec.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, really, because a thread *needs* to be waiting in order to start the new work at the appropriate time.  Your current version is the minimal solution, with 1 "idle" thread.

Comment: cached thread pool creates a thread if it doesn't exist. I can think of a timer + cached thread pool combo.

Comment: @Simply_me Timer has a thread internally.  that doesn't change anything.

Comment: ok, what's the best approach not to leave idle threads around?

Comment: @Simply_me you already asked that in your original question and i already stated that you _have_ to have one thread hanging around.